# Understanding puts output

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to understand the output when using `puts`. I know that `puts` really returns nil, however, I ran across something when working with Hashes.

I wanted the following block to output every key/value pair in a certain format using string interpolation, however, even though `puts` works as intended, I noticed that my terminal prints the entire hash as well, as you see below. I was wondering how to prevent this.

```
@hash.each do |key,val|
    puts "[#{key}] '#{val}'"
end 

[fish] 'aquatic animal'
[zebra] 'African land animal with stripes'
[apple] 'fruit'
=> {"fish"=>"aquatic animal", "zebra"=>"African land animal with stripes", "apple"=>"fruit"}
```

Comment: Actually the "terminal" doesn't print anything, it's the code that is running that prints it. The terminal only displays it. If you run your code using `ruby some_script.rb`, you won't see the returned value from `each` because there isn't a `puts`; You'd need `puts @hash.each ...`. Because you have the output it appears you're using IRB or Pry, rather than Ruby directly, and that is confusing you about what is really happening. IRB/Pry are very useful tools but you have to keep their differences from the Ruby interpreter in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The `each` method always returns the thing it was iterating over, it doesn't return the value the block provides. Presumably this is so you can chain together multiple `each` calls to run through something multiple times if necessary.

Keep in mind methods that take blocks are under no obligation to use whatever values those blocks return, nor are they obligated to even run the block.

As The Tin Man points out the display here is actually an artifact of the `irb` REPL, something that stands for "Read-Evaluate-Print-Loop". You're seeing the result of evaluating your `each` call, which is the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal always outputs the result of last method, `each` in your case. Each returns collection, so it outputs collection. You can slightly change your code to return nil, it prevents long output.

```
@hash.each do |key,val|
    puts "[#{key}] '#{val}'"
end; nil
```